# Good idea to catch HttpException?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exception, httpexception

I have the following error in my output.aspx page sometimes:

> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Request timed out.]

Is it a good idea to catch this exception? Where do I do that as my output.aspx.cs has a Page_Load and that function calls RunTable(). Should I put a try catch block around that functions content?

Comment: Catching an exception is almost always a rather _bad idea_. Better solve the root/cause of the exception, not the symptoms (i.e. the exception).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

catch exception at application level

```
    void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

  // Get the exception object.
  Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();

  // Handle HTTP errors
  if (exc.GetType() == typeof(HttpException))
  {
    // The Complete Error Handling Example generates
    // some errors using URLs with "NoCatch" in them;
    // ignore these here to simulate what would happen
    // if a global.asax handler were not implemented.
      if (exc.Message.Contains("NoCatch") || exc.Message.Contains("maxUrlLength"))
      return;

    //Redirect HTTP errors to HttpError page
    Server.Transfer("HttpErrorPage.aspx");
  }

  // For other kinds of errors give the user some information
  // but stay on the default page
  Response.Write("<h2>Global Page Error</h2>\n");
  Response.Write(
      "<p>" + exc.Message + "</p>\n");
  Response.Write("Return to the <a href='Default.aspx'>" +
      "Default Page</a>\n");

  // Log the exception and notify system operators
  ExceptionUtility.LogException(exc, "DefaultPage");
  ExceptionUtility.NotifySystemOps(exc);

  // Clear the error from the server
  Server.ClearError();
}
```

Comment: where do i put this code? in my output.aspx or output.aspx.cs or somewhere else?

Comment: in global.asax file http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: if it's in my global.asax file, will the response.write code in your answer be put back into my output file as output?

Comment: While it is good to have a central error handler as a _last ressort_, I do believe he should better find and fix the _cause_ of the exception.

Comment: @UweKeim I am agree, first have a central error handler to be sure to catch errors secondly manage exception at low level as possible

Comment: i would find the cause but it's pretty complex. The app sends a stored procedure to the sql server which runs a bunch of sql assemblies in a single thread and does a bunch of statistical computations, thus running some very crazy math problems on multiple browsers casued sql server to slow, thus the web app times out sometimes.